# Flutter FCM: App crashes when receiving message

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I am using FCM plugin for my Flutter app. However, whenever I send a new cloud message to the Android Emulator and the emulator receives it (no matter foreground or background message), the app crashes.

- Flutter run app with an android emulator
- Go to Firebase Console Cloud Messaging
- Send new notifications to android app
- Android emulator receives message and crash

```
import'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'homepage.dart';
import 'notificationservices.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await Notification_Services.NotiSettings();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

HomePage

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'notificationservices.dart';
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});
  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
     Notification_Services.NotiSettings();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
       Text("Data"),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Notification_Services class

```
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
Future<void> BackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message )async{
  log("Remote Message =${message.notification!.title}");
}
class Notification_Services {
  //initialization of firebase messaging

  static Future<void> NotiSettings() async {

    NotificationSettings Settings =
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.requestPermission();
    if (Settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
      log("Initialied Successfully");
      FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(BackgroundHandler);
      FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) {

        log("Remote Message =${message.notification!.title}");

      });

    }
  }
}
```

debug console:
`Process: com.example.googlee, PID: 18130 E/AndroidRuntime(18130): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.example.googlee.java.MyFirebaseMessagingService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.googlee.java.MyFirebaseMessagingService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file`

[debug console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiwBl.png)
[app crash on background pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2L2Eh.jpg)

[pubspec.yaml pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThW4E.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you see the same when using a real device? I used the same code you shared but was not able to reproduce the error. Did you did some extra configuration? try running this sample and see if the same happens: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-flutter/tree/main/messaging